# how to pass values from child pop up window to parent page using angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a parent page in which through one link a pop up window appears and I want to pass the input values to parent page when ok button is pressed. I have also used service to store the value but I think service methods are called when the page loads and since i have to pass the value from child to parent so page is not loaded again so values are not persisting. Can anyone please help me out in this.

This is my parent page :

```
<!-- Here I want to show the values which I got from child. But in tree-data="domain"
     I am not getting the values which i pass from child html -->
<swt-tree tree-data="domain" 
          tree-control="statementTree" 
          label-provider="domainLabelProvider" 
          content-provider="domainContentProvider" 
          expand-level="-1">
</swt-tree>

<!-- Here My Child html will load -->
<div ui-view></div>
```

This is my Child.html

```
<form ng-controller="domainController">
  <input type="text" 
         ng-model="busdomain.name" 
         ng-change="nameChanged()">


  <!-- Here in tree-data="statements" I am getting the values passed from Child.html -->
  <swt-tree tree-data="statements" 
            on-select="statementSelected(branch, selected_branches)" 
            tree-control="statementTree" label-provider="domainLabelProvider" 
            content-provider="domainContentProvider" 
            expand-level="-1"></swt-tree> 

  <button type="submit" ng-click="addSubTree(createdomain.$valid)">OK</button>
</form>
```

This is my controller.js

```
controller('domainController', ['$scope', '$state', 'DomainNameService', function($scope, $state, DomainNameService) {  
    $scope.activeTab = 1;
    $scope.statements=[];
    var statementTree = {};
    $scope.statementTree = statementTree = {};
    $scope.domain = DomainNameService.getDomainName();
    $scope.addSubTree = function(val){
var varType = "busDomain";
                    var domain=[];
                    var busDomain=$scope.busdomain.name;
                    var parent = DomainNameService.getDomainName()[0];              $scope.currentDomainName=$scope.getBusDomain(busDomain,parent,varType);
                        $scope.statements.push($scope.currentDomainName);
                        $scope.statementTree.setNewInput($scope.statements);
                        DomainNameService.addBusDomain($scope.busdomain.name); 
                        $scope.domain.domainName = DomainNameService.getBusDomainName[0];
    //I am passing values here to service but later on this values resets to some previous value..I don't know how to persist the values in $scope.domain.domainname
                    $state.go('DomainTree');
                }
    $scope.getBusDomain = function(stType,parent,varType) {
            return {node:[{name:parent}],name:parent, child:[{name:stType,refType: varType}], childNode:stType, refType: varType};  
        }
```

This is my Service.js

```
app.factory('DomainNameService', function() {
    var busDomainValue=[];      
    var busDomain = undefined;
    return{     
    addBusDomain: function(busDomName){
        busDomainValue.push(busDomName);
    },
   getBusDomainName: function(){
        return busDomainValue;
    }
    }
})
```

Please some one help me out in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you ask for help, it would be courteous to remove as much of irrelevant code an markup/style as possible. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have removed irrelevant code and style

Comment: This is not nearly enough. You should be able to reduce the code to bare minimum to illustrate your specific issue. What is `<swt-tree>`? Is this critical to your question? Can it be any other built-in directive (if it is a directive)? Would a single function/variable in `DomainNameService` suffice to show your issue? Same about the controller. And why do you think it's important to see all the `<div>`s and all the `class` attributes?

Comment: i am trying to create a tree on on parent page that's why <swt-tree> directive is used. Am not able to all the tree node on on parent page

Comment: Is your problem specific to `<swt-tree>` (and if so, can you provide a link to this library)? Or is it more generic... And, I've edited your question somewhat to show what I mean by removing clutter. I'm sure there is a bunch of stuff you could remove from the controller.

Comment: https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree this is the link which I refered for creating tree